# Can I order PCB/chip manufacture from provided LOTOS specification?

Tags: pcb-design, c, pcb-fabrication, asic, model

Is there a way to automatically deduct PCB and/or chip design from **formal problem specification** of a problem (task) which supposed to be solved on a PCB/chip?

I'm currently implementing solution with OpenCL to be run on GPGPU in conjunction with CPU. To decide which part of an algorithm must be run on CPU and which on GPU I had to manually calculate speed of sorting on CPU and GPU and divide by speed of GPU <-> CPU communication.

All sorts of such problems, I think, can be solved automatically by applying of **problem description** upon **hardware specification**.
Googling all of these brought me to pretty complicated and abstract topic of [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) where [LOTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Of_Temporal_Ordering_Specification) seems to be one of them.
I learned a little bit of electronics and know that in-circuit electronic processes and components are very well mathematically defined and deterministic, so automatic PCB/chip layout must be able to be deducted from **problem description**. But I can't find any working tools/libs which can already do it.

I wonder if there is already working solution of how to do it?

P.S. Problem I'm trying to solve is about ~50 lines of somewhat close-to-machine specification, but I had to write already ~5000 OpenCL/C++ code to run the solution upon a device which at first glance is at least 10000(!) times less effective (speed*power-wise) than analog ASIC would be. I feel like I wanna cry :(

Somewhat close task specification of my problem in C-like pseudocode:

```
[declarations]
struct A { float Temp; float Value };
A Mem[ MEM_COUNT ];
A Cur[ CUR_COUNT ];

[process #1]
A S;
S.Value = getCurrentInputValue( attachedCamera/Mic/textFile/etc. );
S.Temp = 1;
Cur[ end ] = S;
for each C in Cur:
    C.Temp += 1 - mod( C.Value - S.Value ) / C.Value;
approximately sort Cur by Temp;

[process #2]
A C = Cur[ 0 ];
for each M in Mem:
    float sum = 0;
    //farthest set is defined as each (MEM_COUNT / FARTHEST_COUNT)'th A starting from M
    for each farthest of M:
        sum += farthest.Value / FARTHEST_COUNT;
    M.Temp -= mod( sum - M.Value );

[process #3]
A M = find M with the most Temp from Mem[];
outputValueToAttachedPin( M.Value );
```

And I would like to tweak MEM_COUNT, CUR_COUNT and FARTHEST_COUNT to see the resulting speed/price/power/etc. As I know, today's CPUs designed so that a program needs to do ~300 operations per every memory access, but in algorithm above it goes up to FARTHEST_COUNT accesses per operation. So, ASIC would be 300*FARTHEST_COUNT times more efficient?

Comment: my analog ics are 1000x more efficient than an equivalent digital implementation.  it's easy to see why from physics.  look for the open access papers on processing by prof jennifer hasler

Comment: @bdegnan OMG are you telepathist? I specifically compared to **analog ASIC** since in my opinion exactly my problem could be solved by a IC mostly consisting of op-amps, because algorithm is just a bunch of comparisons if value less or more than other. But seems like there is a more specific area out there ... awesome!

Comment: There are people trying to build neural network chips for exactly this reason, although I don't know if they're commercially available yet. There is also the Cypress PSOC: http://www.cypress.com/products/psoc-analog-coprocessor

Comment: @pjc50 could you please clarify: do they try to build a chip which will be a neural network or they try to build a neural network which supposed to build chips based on problem description?

Comment: @Slav There's a language also that solves your problem: PYNN.  We use that to program our neural network ICs.

Comment: The former: http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1328877 , http://www.cognimem.com/products/chips-and-modules/CM1K-Chip/ ; there was some work on doing the latter but it's never been terribly successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. Formal methods have successful uses in restricted domains : static timing analysis (that an FPGA or other digital circuit) meets the timing constraints you ask for, for one example.

It can also prove properties about software or hardware - such as correctness of a program written in SPARK (based on Ada) - eliminating the need for runtime checks, guaranteeing the impossibility of buffer overruns, integer overflows, etc.

A little more generally, formal can potentially prove the equivalence of two designs - or a design and a higher level specification - exposing errors in the design, for example. See "equivalence checking" in ASIC design - hasn't made it down to FPGA tools yet, as far as I know.

But formal methods don't - yet - allow synthesis of a detailed design at a high level. (One could argue that a compiler is a formal translation of a "high level" specification in C or Ada, into an assembly language design, but I don't think you'd regard C as sufficiently high level, and I'd agree.

In any case, comments suggest you are dealing in the analog domain, which is arguably even more backward, SPICE netlists still seem to be state of the art. You may wish to flesh out the question with something specific - perhaps illustrating 1 or 5 of your 50 lines of specification, to give us a better idea what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I added C-like pseudocode of an algorithm to the question. Aside question: can you generate PCB/chip layout from SPICE netlist?

Comment: No, as SPICE netlists are specialised for circuit simulation and may not match the physical topology (they may add capacitors to reflect parasitic capacitances, for example). But given a PCB netlist - possibly from the same design database -  it may be possible to auto-place, and it's certainly possible to auto-route a PCB. So, to some extent, yes. How good a job they do is another matter.

Comment: Hm, if PCB layout cannot be generated from even SPICE netlists, then I definitely have to give up on even broader problem-->hardware_manufacture. But I really wonder why not, since machine can [analyze](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/Slots/cache/www.itu.dk/research/buddy/) every [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) layout and choose the best one? I really can't see how human can make it any better than machine would... even if human has infinite time. Sorry for my newbie mumbling..just wondering...

Comment: Layout is probably NP Complete for a formal 'BEST' whatever that means (And no two layout guys would lay out a board the same way). Now there are some ways to find an  'approximately best' (For various values of both approximately and best), much as there are polynomial time approximations to travelling salesman, but every possible layout (with possible back annotation where appropriate is a HUGE configuration space). Don't forget that a spice netlist will probably not list pinout details, let alone little things that every good layout guy knows (Ceramic caps near sheer lines!).